# Why does echo “$USER:staff” throw zsh: bad substitution?

Tags: zsh

Puzzled because `echo "PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin"` doesn’t (thought it had something to do with `:`).

Also, in Bash, both commands work as I expected.

```
$ echo "PATH=$PATH"
PATH=/usr/local/bin

$ echo "PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin"
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin

$ echo "$USER:staff"
zsh: bad substitution
```

Comment: Hint: `foo=bar; echo "$foo:s/r/X/"`

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Interesting... is that sed string substitution? So why does the `$PATH` command work?

Comment: @glennjackman I believe I fixed the typo.

Comment: Because `:/` is different than `:s`. I don't know Zsh good enough to write a decent answer though.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Ok... I think I get it now... `:s` is interpreted as string substitution.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Is it recommended to always use `${PATH}`, `${USER}`, etc... then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `:s` after `$USER` is interpreted as an [expansion modifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers). You can see this clearly if you do the following:

```bash
% autoload -Uz compinit; compinit       # Init completion system
% zstyle ':completion:*' group-name ''  # Enable completion grouping
% zstyle ':completion:*' format '%d'    # Add titles to the groups
% print $USER: # and press Tab or ^D right after the `:`
modifier
&  -- repeat substitution
A  -- as ':a', then resolve symlinks
P  -- realpath, resolve '..' physically
Q  -- strip quotes
a  -- absolute path, resolve '..' lexically
c  -- PATH search for command
e  -- leave only extension
g  -- globally apply s or &
h  -- head - strip trailing path element
l  -- lower case all words
q  -- quote to escape further substitutions
r  -- root - strip suffix
s  -- substitute string
t  -- tail - strip directories
u  -- upper case all words
```

And as you can see from the list above, `:/` is not an expansion modifier.

> Is it recommended to always use `${PATH}`, `${USER}`, etc... then?

No, it's usually fine to just use `$USER`, but *sometimes,* as you can see, it is required to use `${USER}`. :)

However, regarding the code in your question, I can give you two other recommendations to use in Zsh:

- Use [`$path` instead of `$PATH`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Parameters-Used-By-The-Shell) and
- use
  [`print`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-print)
  instead of `echo`.

```bash
% print $PATH
/usr/local/bin

% print $path
/usr/local/bin

% path+=/usr/local/sbin  # $path is an array, not a string

% print $PATH            # $path and $PATH are "tied" & automatically in sync
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin

% print -c $path         # Print the items in columns, like `ls`
/usr/local/bin   /usr/local/sbin

% print -l $path         # Print one item per line, like `ls -l`
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/sbin

% path+=/usr/local/sbin

% print -c $path       
/usr/local/bin   /usr/local/sbin  /usr/local/sbin

% typeset -U PATH path   # Make each item unique/Eliminate duplicates

% print -c $path       
/usr/local/bin   /usr/local/sbin
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for helping out Marlon!